# Application to browse a Node.js package code

Tags: node.js

I want to browse through [hubot](https://github.com/github/hubot)'s code using some kind of summarized representation of methods. I like [YARD](http://yardoc.org/) in Ruby because it does exactly that for Gems.

What tool (offline or online) can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/args/index.html. This is the YUIDoc tool which is a NodeJS application.

The page provides information about the usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found this excellent package: https://github.com/netzpirat/codo, which is actually based in YARD, and produces documentation just like it.

[image]